# Linespacing changes randomly

Tags: line-spacing, appendices

In my latex document I'm using a linespacing of 1.5. For the appendix I set it to 1.1 with the linespread command:

```
\begin{appendix}
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{}{}{}{}{}
    \linespread{1.1}\selectfont
    \section{Appendix}
      \subsection{Test 1}
      Lorem ipsum ...
      \subsection{Test 2}
      Lorem ipsum ...
\end{appendix}
```

This works for the whole appendix, except for the last subsection, no matter how many subsections there are. There it just randomly switches back to a linespacing of 1.5 again. Even if I put the linespread command in this last subsection it wont have the linespacing. Any clues how I could apply the linespacing to the whole appendix?

Comment: it's not random, it just follows your instructions, leave a blank line before `\end{appendix}` (`\appendix` is not really designed to be used as an environment)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's not a good idea to manipulate the lowel-level parameter `\linespread` directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue instructions such as `\setstretch{1.5}` and `\setstretch{1.1}`.

Comment: Thank you both very much. The first suggestion works fine. What a tiny change to make! But given the problems I decided to follow the second suggestion to use `\setstretch{1.1}`

Comment: you need the blank line anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `\appendix` had been designed as an environment, then `\endappendix` would have been defined to add `\par` which is equivalent to a blank line and avoided the problem. As it is `\end{appendix}` is just `\endgroup` as such you have something equivalent to

```
\begingroup
\linespread{1.1}\selectfont
a paragraph of text
\endgroup

..
```

The linespacing is a paragraph parameter and the value used is the value at the *end* of the paragraph. The paragraph ends at the blank line *after* the group ends, at which point the values have reset to the values they had before the group. If instead you have

```
\begingroup
\linespread{1.1}\selectfont
a paragraph of text

\endgroup

..
```

Then the paragraph ends at the blank line before the group ends and so is set with the local paragraph settings.